# Interface Oracle database to a SQL Server database using BizTalk

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, biztalk

I am having hard time with creating a stored procedure to insert/update the selected records from an Oracle database to a SQL Server database using BizTalk.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspInsertorUpdateINF]
@dp_id                char(32),
@dv_id                char(32),
@em_number            char(12),
@email                varchar(50),
@emergency_relation   char(32),
@option1              char(16),
@status               char(20),
@em_id                char(35),
@em_title             varchar(64),
@date_hired           datetime
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

MERGE [dbo].[em] AS [Targ]
USING (VALUES (@dp_id, @dv_id , @em_number, @email, @emergency_relation, @option1, @status, @em_id, @em_title, @date_hired))
AS [Sourc] (dp_id, dv_id, em_number, email, emergency_relation, option1, status, em_id, em_title, date_hired)  
  ON [Targ].em_id = [Sourc].em_id

  WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE 
     SET dp_id                 = [Sourc].dp_id,
         dv_id                 = [Sourc].dv_id,
         em_number             = [Sourc].em_number,
         email                 = [Sourc].email,
         emergency_relation    = [Sourc].emergency_relation,
         option1               = [Sourc].option1,
         status                = [Sourc].status,
         em_title              = [Sourc].em_title,
         date_hired            = [Sourc].date_hired

 WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT (dp_id, dv_id, em_number, email, emergency_relation, option1, status, em_id, em_title,date_hired)
  VALUES ([Sourc].dp_id, [Sourc].dv_id, [Sourc].em_number, [Sourc].email, [Sourc].emergency_relation, [Sourc].option1, [Sourc].status, [Sourc].em_id, [Sourc].em_title, [Sourc].date_hired);

 END;
```

It just insert one record from the Oracle DB to the SQL Database. But select the entire set of records using the below line

```
<ns0:Select xmlns:ns0="http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/View/VW_EMP30D"><ns0:COLUMN_NAMES>*</ns0:COLUMN_NAMES><ns0:FILTER></ns0:FILTER></ns0:Select>
```

What should I do here to insert/ update entire set of records in to SQL database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your Stored Procedure only takes one set (row really) of parameters so, yes, it will only update one row.

You have two options:

1. Use this Stored Procedure as part of a WCF SQL Composite Operation where you can Map each Oracle result to an individual instance of this SP.
2. Use a Table Value Parameter as your Stored Procedure parameter.

These Wiki articles have samples of each procedure:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26279.biztalk-streamlining-wcf-sql-and-oracle-messaging-only-and-other-patterns.aspx

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24803.biztalk-server-sql-patterns-for-polling-and-batch-retreive.aspx